# Disable caching of operations when connection is down in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a collaborative editor with firebase, to do so I am queuing a list of operations to send updates to the file (similar to what is described in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEoWPdQh27c).

I am sending the operations through a transaction, similar so the one described in the file, like this:

```
Future<void> sendOperations(List<SyncedOperationMixin> operations) async {
  var currentStep = this.currentStepIndex;

  return firestore.runTransaction(
    (transaction) async {
      final currentStepDoc = stepsReference.doc(getStepDocumentName(currentStep + 1));  
      
      // If the document with the next-most step id exists, we need to rebase (throw an error)
    
      // otherwise, upload the operations
    },
    maxAttempts: 1,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 2),
  ).then((r) {
    this.currentStepIndex = currentStep;
  });
```

Then I have a loop that sends the operations and wait for the sendOperation calls, an in case they fail needing a rebase, it schedules a rebase, otherwise if any other error is thrown, it retries after a delay.

I would have expected firebase to fail after [timeout] if connection is absent, with some kind of error, but instead it appears to cache the transaction and run it when the network is online again.

This does not work for me for multiple reasons such as:

- if operations from a batch fail to send due to connection errors, I can send them with the next batch (which if firestore caches the operation does not work as they never fail)
- Caching means that they refer to old data, such as old stepIndexes
- They would always fail when reapplying them if the connection stays down for a long time (as other users are likely to have done edits in the meanwhile)

Is there a way to tell firebase not to queue/cache operations and instead fail them if the connection is down?

(I am working with the flutter api in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

So if your transactions don't fail after a certain amount of time (that might be `maxAttempts x timeout`) that means it's not working according to its documentation, and you should probably file a bug for it.

But in the code you shared, I don't see you interacting with the `transaction` at all, so that might explain why there's no failure.

---

I tried reproducing the problem [here](https://zapp.run/edit/firestore-transactions-offline-z7fq06k28fr0?file=lib/main.dart:864-1552), with this code:

```
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

var col = db.collection("77140341");
var doc = col.doc("test");

doc.snapshots().listen((read) {
  print('Read document: ${read.data()}');
});

print('Wating 5 seconds, now would be a good time to disable your network');
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
print('Starting transaction');
try {
  await db.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      print('Reading and updating version field in ${doc.path}');
      final snapshot = await doc.get();
      transaction.update(doc, {'version': snapshot.get('version') + 1});
    },
    maxAttempts: 1,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
  );
  print('Transaction completed');
}
catch (error) {
  print('Error while running transaction: $error');
}
```

If I disconnect my network just before this runs, I get error messages indicating the lack of a network connection:

> [11:21:41] This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
> [11:21:41] Firestore (9.18.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
> [11:21:41] [2023-09-20T09:21:41.481Z]  @firebase/firestore:
> [11:21:41] [object Object]
> [11:21:41] RPC 'Listen' stream 0x1d862c69 transport errored:
> [11:21:41] Firestore (9.18.0): WebChannelConnection
> [11:21:41] [2023-09-20T09:21:41.480Z]  @firebase/firestore:
> [11:21:42] Error while running transaction: [cloud_firestore/unavailable] Connection failed.

If I subsequently reestablish the network connection, the transaction does **not** complete. This is the expected behavior, given the timeout value specified in the call.